# ASP.Net MVC 5 Plantilla Scaffolding No muestra la propiedad relacionada en la View Details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Cree el Modelo Libro:
[image: Clase Libro]

Luego el Modelo Materia
[image: Clase Materia]

Luego Cree Los Controlers y les asigné los Modelos y generó las Views, aquí en la View Details.cshtml, cuando navego desde la lista de registros de Libros a través del link Detail, no me muestra el valor del atributo Materia

[image: Vista Details de La Clase Libro]

Hay algo que no estoy viendo? cómo puedo mostrar el valor del atributo en la vista de detalles?

Editado: Agrego en texto el código del Controller de la clase Libro:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InventarioLibros.Models;

namespace InventarioLibros.Controllers
{
public class LibrosController : Controller
{
    private InventarioLibrosContext db = new InventarioLibrosContext();

    // GET: Libros
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var libros = db.Libros.Include(l => l.MateriaLibro).Include(l => l.UbicacionLibro);
        return View(libros.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Libros/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Libro libro = db.Libros.Find(id);
        if (libro == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(libro);
    }

    // GET: Libros/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.MateriaId = new SelectList(db.Materias, "MateriaId", "Nombre");
        ViewBag.UbicacionId = new SelectList(db.Ubicaciones, "UbicacionId", "Nombre");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Libros/Create
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LibroId,Titulo,Autor,Año,Paginas,MateriaId,UbicacionId")] Libro libro)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Libros.Add(libro);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.MateriaId = new SelectList(db.Materias, "MateriaId", "Nombre", libro.MateriaId);
        ViewBag.UbicacionId = new SelectList(db.Ubicaciones, "UbicacionId", "Nombre", libro.UbicacionId);
        return View(libro);
    }

    // GET: Libros/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Libro libro = db.Libros.Find(id);
        if (libro == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.MateriaId = new SelectList(db.Materias, "MateriaId", "Nombre", libro.MateriaId);
        ViewBag.UbicacionId = new SelectList(db.Ubicaciones, "UbicacionId", "Nombre", libro.UbicacionId);
        return View(libro);
    }

    // POST: Libros/Edit/5
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "LibroId,Titulo,Autor,Año,Paginas,MateriaId,UbicacionId")] Libro libro)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(libro).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.MateriaId = new SelectList(db.Materias, "MateriaId", "Nombre", libro.MateriaId);
        ViewBag.UbicacionId = new SelectList(db.Ubicaciones, "UbicacionId", "Nombre", libro.UbicacionId);
        return View(libro);
    }

    // GET: Libros/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Libro libro = db.Libros.Find(id);
        if (libro == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(libro);
    }

    // POST: Libros/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Libro libro = db.Libros.Find(id);
        db.Libros.Remove(libro);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hola Christian bienvenido te invito a que en lugar de imágenes publiques tu código ya que así es mas fácil que la gente de la comunidad pueda ayudarte  :D

Comment: Christian necesitamso más código, si puedes pon el cod de tu controlador y de tus calses implicadas

Comment: @Xique : Cómo se hace más fácil poner texto en vez de imagenes?

Comment: @VicenteAlmea : Las clases implicadas están ahí... son Libro y Materia, el Controller es el que se arma por defecto con la plantilla, pondré el código..

Comment: @ChristianCuadrosBetancur si asi como pusiste el codigo de tus metodos pon el codigo de tus clases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la declaración del modificador virtual en el atributo MateriaLibro en la línea 20 de la clase Libro es lo que necesitaba para que el EF use su Lazy Loading para cargar la propiedad

Answer (score 0):

Con el modificador virtual en el atributo MateriaLibro funciona perfectamente, también puedes utilizar otra via, modificando tu query LINQ en el controlador ejemplo:

```
  // GET: /Libros/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var libro = db.Libros.Include(l=>l.MateriaLibro).FirstOrDefault(l=>l.LibroId == id);
            if (libro == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(libro);
        }
```

Utilizando `Include` EF carga los datos de la Materia, esta via puedes tomarla en cuenta ya que traté de realizar tu ejemplo en una App Asp.Net Core 2 y no funciona, sin embargo esta vía si funciona en todos los casos. Espero te sea de utilidad